# Water making its way out of the shower pan, bubbling laminate floor. Grout in shower floor stays wet

Tags: plumbing, shower, tile, leak, grout

How do I keep the water **inside** my shower??
I'm getting water blisters in the laminate floor outside my shower. 
[image: bubbles in floor]
My shower is about 3 years old. The enclosure was hot-mopped hardie-backer cement board. Tile is 12x18" slate with sanded grout, with slabs of old pool table slate used for the seat and curb top. The floor is ceramic penny-round mosaic on mesh backing. 
[image]
The laminate floor in front of my shower curb started developing blister-looking bubbles. When I popped one, there was water inside. When we don't use the shower for a day, the bubbles flatten out! So, it looks like there's water wicking out of the shower and down to the edge of the laminate flooring, where the flooring butts up against the shower. There aren't any obvious leaks in the ceiling underneath the shower, and no surface water on the floor outside after showering. 
The grout stays wet in some spots. I ground out the grout where the walls meet the floor, starting with the dark wet spots. [image: wet grout]Found some voids in the grout under the wall tiles. I turned on a hairdryer on one of the spots and the dark moisture went away after a few hours, but when I turned the hairdryer on to a new spot, the old spot got wet again! I took the drain cover off and it looks like the weep holes *might* have been plugged. I cleared them, and there does seem to be pea gravel behind the holes. [image]
There are a couple cracks in the penny rounds on the floor of the shower. Also there is a crack where the chunk of pool table we used to cover the top of the curb seems to have lifted off the curb framing. [image: curb pic upside down]Maybe water got in and the wood swelled. 
How do I keep the blisters from returning?

Answer (score 1):

Need more pics but an educated guess will is
1 the laminate is *NOT* approved for all wet areas.
2. Seal your  grout its not waterproof

Comment: For sure. What pictures would help?